# Fix div to bottom of parent

Tags: html, css

i have the following HTML/CSS:

```
<div id="blockcart-wrapper">
  <div class="blockcart cart-preview">
    <div class="header">
      <a rel="nofollow" href="#">
        <img class="cart-icon" src="https://via.placeholder.com/20x20" onclick="toggleClass()">

      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="body" id="shopping-cart-body">
      <div class="close"><a href="" onclick="toggleClass()">X</a></div>
      <ul>
      </ul>
      <div class="shopping-cart-header">CART</div>
      <div class="products-container">
        <div class="product">
          <span class="prodcut-image"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/250x100"></span>
          <div class="product-details">
            <div class="name-header">NAME</div>
            <div class="product-quantity-details">
              <span class="quantity">QTY</span>
              <span class="color-circle"></span>
              <span class="color">COLOR</span>
            </div>
            <div class="price-open">
              <span class="product-price">XX.XX</span>
              <span class="product-link"><a href="#">öffnen</a></span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
      <div class="checkout">
        <div class="taxes">
          <span class="label">Taxes</span>
          <span class="value">0</span>
        </div>
        <div class="cart-total">
          <span class="label">Total</span>
          <span class="value">0</span>
        </div>
        <button><a href="#">Checkout</a></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.cart-preview .body {
  visibility: visible;
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  width: 400px;
  z-index: 100;
  background-color: #fff;
  transition: right 1s linear;
  right: -400px;
}

.cart-preview .body.open {
  visibility: visible;
  transition: right 1s linear;
  right: 0px;
}

.cart-preview .body .shooping-cart-body {
  font-family: 'sans-serif';
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.cart-preview .body .close{
  float: left;
}
.cart-preview .body .shooping-cart-header{
  text-align: center;
}
.cart-preview .body .products-container {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 15px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.product {
  display: flex;
}

.product>div {
  width: 50%;
}

.product .prodcut-image {
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.product img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.cart-preview .body .products-container>.product-image {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  left: 0;
}

.cart-preview .body .products-container>.product-details {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  float: right;
}

.cart-preview .body .products-container .color-circle:before {
  content: ' \25CF';
  font-size: 30px;
}

.cart-preview .body .checkout {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.product-quantity-details .quantity{
  border: 2px solid black;
  margin: 0 10px;
  background: white;
  width: 36px;
  height: 36px;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 15px;
  color: black;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
}

.product-quantity-details .quantity:after{
  content: 'x'
}

.cart-preview .body .checkout>button {
  position: absolute;
  background: black;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  bottom: 50px;
  height: 20px;
  width: 205px;
  left: 25%;
}

.taxes {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  left: 0;
}

.cart-total {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100px;
  width: 100%;
}

.taxes {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 300px;
  width: 100%;
}

.cart-total .value {
  float: right;
}
.cart-total .value:after {
  content:'€'
}

.cart-total .label {
  float: left;
}

.taxes .value {
  float: right;
}

.taxes .label {
  float: left;
}

.cart-preview.cart-overview {
  width: 100%;
  position: inherit;
}
.cart-preview.cart-overview .body {
  display: block;
  position: inherit;
  width: 100%;
}
.cart-preview .header > :first-child {
  float: left;
}
.cart-preview .header > :last-child {
  float: right;
}
.cart-preview .header::after,
.cart-preview .cart-totals > div::after {
  clear: both;
  content: "\A0";
}
.cart-preview .body {
  border: 1px solid #808080;
  padding: 2px;
}
```

The JavaScript simply toggles the .open class for the body.
Now I want to stick the last div to the bottom of the body, so the product-container div is scrollable on overflow and the checkout is always visible.
However, neither the scrolling nor the chechkout divs position are working.
Could someone help me with these two things?

Comment: I tried creating the same scenario you are facing by copy your code and understanding your problem but it is not showing anything in viewport.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean :(

Comment: I am not able to understand completely and my answer is based on my understanding of your problem.

Comment: I want to have the whole checkout div sticky to the bottom with about 20% of the complete height of shopping-cart-body. Will try your answer soon:)

Comment: I dont see the `toggleClass` function ?

Comment: Yea I didn't pasted her because she only does toggleClass('open') on the body div

Comment: "Now I want to stick the last div to the bottom of the body": which body do you mean the body tag or the div with class body ?

Comment: the .body div that contains all the content. sorry if that was not clear

Answer (score 0):

Please try this and provide feedback so, that answer can be improved more.

```
 .cart-preview .body {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  width: 400px;
  z-index: 100;
  background-color: #fff;
  transition: right 1s linear;
}

.cart-preview .body.open {
  visibility: visible;
  transition: right 1s linear;
  right: 0px;
}

.cart-preview .body .shooping-cart-body {
  font-family: 'sans-serif';
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.cart-preview .body .close{
  float: left;
}
.cart-preview .body .shooping-cart-header{
  text-align: center;
}
.cart-preview .body .products-container {
  position: relative;
  max-height: 400px;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 15px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.product {
  display: flex;
}

.product>div {
  width: 50%;
}

.product .prodcut-image {
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.product img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.cart-preview .body .products-container>.product-image {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  left: 0;
}

.cart-preview .body .products-container>.product-details {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  float: right;
}

.cart-preview .body .products-container .color-circle:before {
  content: ' \25CF';
  font-size: 30px;
}

.product-quantity-details .quantity{
  border: 2px solid black;
  margin: 0 10px;
  background: white;
  width: 36px;
  height: 36px;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 15px;
  color: black;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
}

.product-quantity-details .quantity:after{
  content: 'x'
}

.cart-preview .body .checkout>button {
  position: relative;
  background: black;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  height: 20px;
  width: 205px;
}

.taxes {
  position: relative;
}

.cart-total .value {
  float: right;
}
.cart-total .value:after {
  content:'€'
}

.cart-total .label {
  float: left;
}

.taxes .value {
  float: right;
}

.taxes .label {
  float: left;
}

.cart-preview.cart-overview {
  width: 100%;
  position: inherit;
}
.cart-preview.cart-overview .body {
  display: block;
  position: inherit;
  width: 100%;
}
.cart-preview .header > :first-child {
  float: left;
}
.cart-preview .header > :last-child {
  float: right;
}
.cart-preview .header::after,
.cart-preview .cart-totals > div::after {
  clear: both;
  content: "\A0";
}
.cart-preview .body {
  border: 1px solid #808080;
  padding: 2px;
}
```